# Swing - Hebrew punctuation (shva) is displayed wrong

Tags: java, swing, localization, hebrew, punctuation

I'm trying to localize a Swing application with [Hebrew punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_punctuation)

But Shva (U+05B0) is displayed wrong, should be displayed as:

[image]

```
System.out.println("\u05D9\u05B0\u05E6\u05B4\u05D9\u05D0\u05B8\u05D4");
```

Will print correctly the first letter with Shva punctuation:

```
יְצִיאָה
```

But when added to Swing application using messages.properties file

It display `\u05B0` same as `\u05B4`    (HIRIQ)

```
  יִצִיאָה
```

I tried other Unicode option but it didn't work, does anyone have a reason or is there a known limitation ?

It shows the as main menu option it looks OK, as a sub menu (can't enlarger component) it look wrong

Comment: You should really try: 1) Enlarging the font size for example images of programming problems. 2) Crop the image to the relevant part! General tips: 1) See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson this is the size the image is displayed (which may be related to the issue) , I also added text to display the difference between expected to actual

Comment: *"this is the size the image is displayed"* It will display larger on SO if all the useless white part of the image is cropped. As is, I had to open it in a new tab then resize it to full size before I had any hope of identifying what it was beyond a green smudge. *"I also added text to display the difference"* So the image gives nothing new? Remove it completely. Otherwise I'd recommend cropping it so the viewer can see what it contains without jumping through the hoops I had to.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this, though, I forgot to vote to close it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I removed the image